# Visual Basic - How to open a url on a new tab of browser in ASP.NET web forms?

Tags: vb.net, response.redirect

I'm trying to do an integration and I have a url. My ASPxButton is as follows:

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btn1" runat="server"
                    Text="Start Integration" Height="18px" Width="77px">
                    <FocusRectPaddings Padding="0px" />
                </dx:ASPxButton>
```

And my click event is as follows:

```
Protected Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
        
    ......

    Dim urlForNewTab = "https://.../test.html?recordId=" + record.ToString + "&accessToken=" + token

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('" & urlForNewTab & "');", True)

    'btn1.OnClientClick="javascript:window.open('" + urlForNewTab  + "');"

    'Response.Redirect(urlForNewTab )

End Sub
```

I tried many things but it didn't work? I tried to cancel reloading the page, it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I did the instructions in the link below and it worked.

https://www.aspsnippets.com/questions/133817/Open-new-Window-from-Server-side-without-Page-Refresh-in-ASPNet/